# HTTP Status:404 - Not found in Maven Spring mvc project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am stuck in this,i have searched all the alternatives after that posting it.
Please don't mark it as duplicate.
I am using `maven-web-archetype`,after running tomcat server,thhp 404 error coming.
There are no any red markers,nothing.

[image: Project Hierarchy]

`PageController.java` file Controller as follows:

```
package net.vyntra.onlinemart.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class PageController {

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView index()
{
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("page");
    mv.addObject("greeting","Welcome to spring MVC");
    return mv;
}
}
```

`web.xml` file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Configuring front-controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    

</web-app>
```

`dispatcher-servlet.xml` as follows:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:wf="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd        
    ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.vyntra.onlinemart.controller"/>
    

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        
    </bean>
    
    
    
    
    
</beans>
```

`page.jsp` below:

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title>Online Shopping</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Vyntra</h1>
    ${greeting}
</body>

</html>
```

This is the stuff.There are no errors while running.Any extra file that is in herarchy like security.xml,or anything yet not mapped.